# The issue is we're unable to switch between our SMSMessage and EmailMessage during runtime using Spring-Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

We have the following code. The issue arises as we're unable to switch between SMSMessage and EmailMessage during runtime using Spring Boot. Currently, we need to modify the spring.profiles.active=sms entry in the application.properties file and restart the application for this switch. Is there a way to leverage Spring Framework's Dependency Injection (DI) to enable the dynamic exchange between SMSMessage and EmailMessage during runtime without the need for restarting the application?
We use:
springBootVersion=2.7.12
springVersion=5.3.27

ApplicationProperties:
spring.profiles.active=sms

````
package net.portal;

public interface MessageService {
    void sendMessage(String message);
}

@Service
@Profile("!sms")
public class EmailService implements MessageService {
    @Override
    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        // Logic to send an email
        System.out.println("Email sent: " + message);
    }
}

@Service
@Profile("sms")
public class SMSService implements MessageService {
    @Override
    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        // Logic to send an SMS
        System.out.println("SMS sent: " + message);
    }
}

@Component
public class MessageSender {
    private final MessageService messageService;
    @Autowired
    public MessageSender(MessageService messageService) {
        this.messageService = messageService;
    }
    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        messageService.sendMessage(message);
    }
  }
  // Run the message service
  private static ApplicationContext context;
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationLauncher.class, args);
        MessageSender sender = context.getBean(MessageSender.class);
        sender.sendMessage("Hello, this is frm SMS message now!");
    }
   ETC.
```
````

Comment: You would need a feature toggle and not use profiles. Something like https://www.togglz.org/ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the idea is to have an external value that controls what bean you want to use.

One solution is feature flagging.
Another solution is, let's say you have a user and on their profile they have

- email - checked
- sms - unchecked

when sending that message to the user you know that you must send it only through email as their preferences say so.

Then you could use named beans.
`@Qualifier` and `context.getBean("<bean name>");`

Or you could use a map and let spring inject all the beans there like

```
@Service
@Qualifier("email")
public class EmailService implements MessageService {
    ...
}

@Service
@Qualifier("sms")
public class SMSService implements MessageService {
   ....
}

......


@Autowire
private Map<String, MessageService > messageServiceBeansMap;

....

<some other logic here>
var channel = getChannelUsingSomeLogic()
messageServiceBeansMap.getOrDefault(channel, theDefaultChannelBean).sendMessage(..)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a strategy pattern for this idea. just create a notification interface service and 2 impl for that named @Service("Email") and @service("SMS"). then create a factory class named Notification factory and define class level map like `private final Map<String, Notification> notification;`. you need to send a property in your request to handle sms or email and then in a factory method based on this property using the impl with this `notification. get("YOUR_NOTIFICATION_TYPE")`. then execute the send method that defines in notification service that has 2 impl .